# Frame Extraction and Insertion in a Video file (.avi and .mpg) in VB6

Tags: video, vb6

We have a software developed in VB6. This software automates Photoshop to achieve quick single click image corrections.

Now our client has asked us to add support for processing selected frames in a video file.

What we want to achieve is Extract a range of frames from a video file and process them in Photoshop and then insert them back in the video file.

Any ideas as to how we can achieve this?

I have never programmed video handling so I am new to this concept.

Please point me to any libraries that will work in VB6 and that may be providing frame extraction and insertion without disrupting the audio of that video file.

Oh! I should mention that I have tried ImageEnX for this but unfortunately it is not able to handle various codecs and it can work with very short video files (less than 100 MB).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found a way to do this. So I though I will share it with other here.

Of course not as I want it but it just works like a charm. :)

What I am doing?

- I am using FFMPEG to first convert a video and extract all frames
- Then I am extracting Audio from original video
- Then I am processing only those frames that fall into the range selected by user
- Once all frames are processed I am rebuilding Video from frames in **mpeg** format
- Then I am merging the extracted Audio back to the newly generated Video

That is it.

Hope this will help someone searching for similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the AviFile API (VB6 code available at [ShrinkWrapVB](http://www.shrinkwrapvb.com))

Comment: I have already checked this code before posting. This code also cannot handle all kinds of AVI files.

Comment: It handles AVI files, but the codecs depend on which you have installed. To get more domplex, DirectShow/Quartz needs to be used but this is not practical in VB6.